# Need Some Advice on HTML Forms

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql, web

I've been working on an HTML page that displays a table from an SQL database on a second page which is sorted by radio buttons on the first page. My preferred language here is C# and I can't seem to build that second page correctly. Currently I am trying to use IF statements in conjunction with LINQ but it's not working. Can anyone advise me on how to proceed? I am a complete amateur by the way.
HTML Code:

```
     <body>
    <h1>Server Request Form</h1>
    <form id="sortradio" action="searchresults.aspx" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sort Order</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="titledesc" name="sortorder" value="Title Desc" />
            <label for="titledesc">By Title - Descending</label>
            <input type="radio" id="titleasc" name="sortorder" value="Title" />
            <label for="titleasc">By Title - Ascending</label>
            <input type="radio" id="iddesc" name="sortorder" value="Id Desc" />
            <label for="iddesc">By ID - Descending</label>
            <input type="radio" id="idasc" name="sortorder" value="Id" />
            <label for="idasc">By ID - Ascending</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Get Info" />
        </fieldset>
   </form>
</body>
```

Aspx Code:

```
<h1>You are sorting by <% Response.Write(Request.QueryString("sortorder"))%>.</h1>
<% 
    Dim SortingOrder = Request.QueryString("sortorder")
%>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Summary" HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="Summary" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GenreId" HeaderText="GenreId" SortExpression="GenreId" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Authorized" HeaderText="Authorized" SortExpression="Authorized" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDateTime" HeaderText="CreateDateTime" SortExpression="CreateDateTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDateTime" HeaderText="UpdateDateTime" SortExpression="UpdateDateTime" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1.MDFConnectionString1 %>" providername="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1.MDFConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" selectcommand="SELECT [Id], [Title], [Summary], [Body], [GenreId], [Authorized], [CreateDateTime], [UpdateDateTime] FROM [Review] ORDER BY @sortorder">
        <Selectparameters>
      <asp:querystringparameter name="sortorder" querystringfield="sortorder" />
        </Selectparameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>`
```

Comment: It would help if you provided your code that you're using at the moment so we can see why it might not be working..

Comment: what tech are you using? if you are a Csharper, Asp.net Webform or MVC?

Comment: Again.. please show us the code that pertains to the question. You've given us markup.. where are these `if` statements you've mentioned?

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the `if` because pretty much every line contained an error. Is there a way to just do it with asp markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't be using parameters in your ORDER BY clause.

If it were me I would implement an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and create my ORDER BY clause dynamically using server-side hard-coded alternatives. If you go down that route, then make sure to **ALWAYS USE PARAMETERS FOR USER-SUBMITTED DATA TO SECURE YOURSELF AGAINST [SQL INJECTION](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) ATTACKS**.

If you're not up to tackling the ObjectDataSource class, then consider implementing a different SQLDataSource for each of your sort options. Each one will implement a different ORDER BY clause.

Set the DataSourceID based on the value of the query parameter.

Not sure if that works as-is. You may have to set your GridView's DataSource explicitly. If so, remember to call Databind() explicitly too.